# When i checked with function isdigit() two integers, first = 1, and second = 2, it give me false result

Tags: c

Why in my code , `isdigit()` function dont work , when i print `sum` it is 0?
p.s i include `<ctype>` lib

```
int main(void)
{
  int sum = 0;
  int prvi = 0;
  int drugi = 0;

   prvi = 1;
   drugi = 2;

            if ( isdigit(prvi) && isdigit(drugi) )
                sum = prvi + drugi;

    printf("sum: %d \n",sum);
}
```

Comment: Because neither of them are digits in your platform's character representation. See this reference for [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit).

Comment: `isdigit` isn't for integers. Obviously `int` variables contain digits. `isdigit` is for checking whether *characters* contain numeric digits.

Comment: It works when `prvi` and `drugi` is between 48 and 57 because 48 and 57 and `'0'` and `'9'` respectively in the ASCII table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`isdigit` is used to check whether a *character* is a decimal digit - it's unclear to me what character repertoire is used, but I don't know of any character repertoires in which 1 and 2 are characters. Try 48 and 49 for example, which are the ASCII values for '0' and '1'. *Those* should both make `isdigit` return a non-zero result, at least if it's using ASCII.

If you don't have textual data, you don't need to call `isdigit`. It's not clear what you're really trying to achieve, but I suspect `isdigit` is a red herring...

Comment: Thanks, i didn't read about what kind type argument ask for this function.

Answer (score 2):

Reason is it converts those int into char as per Ascii and see's them as non number.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/ shows the signature as accepting an `int` parameter... is it wrong? (No sarcasm - I honestly don't know what counts as a good web reference for the C standard library.)

Comment: Nope, `isDigit` isn't a thing. And `isdigit` takes an `int`.

Comment: @JonSkeet The reference isn't held in high regard by the C++ community, but it is right about the signature of `isdigit`. On a *nix system, `man isdigit` is quite helpful too.

Comment: Indeed it's int but it internally treats that int as Ascii value of int.

Comment: I don't think it is restricted to ascii either.

Answer (score 2):

The `isdigit()` function checks whether a given [ASCII character](http://www.asciitable.com) represents a digit, not whether the type of the *parameter* is a number (after all, the parameter will always be an integer).

For example, the ASCII representation of 'a' is 97, so `isdigit(97)` would return zero. However, '1' is 49, so `isdigit(49)` would return non-zero i.e. "true".

Comment: I don't think it is restricted to ASCII.

Comment: @juanchopanza You're quite right, [it actually depends on the current locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/isdigit.html) - I said ASCII just to keep things simple. Please feel free to edit the answer if you'd like to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

**isdigit(x)** gives you **true** when x is between 48 and 59 inclusive

In Ascci values

48 = 0

49 = 1

.

.

.

57 = 9